# Alfred Hitchcock anthology story involving a psychic barber who is "bald as an egg"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, psychic

This one is nagging at the edge of my mind. It was probably one of Alfred Hitchcock's hardback *Spellbinders of Suspense* anthologies, as we had a few around the house that I read from cover to cover in the 1980s and 1990s. The main character was a barber, described as "bald as an egg" who was apparently constantly cheerful, spouting bromides like "I'm as happy as a lamb in spring" (not an actual quote, I think) when asked how he was doing. His secret was that he could tell the future when doing someone's hair. In the story, a visiting couple asks for a haircut, and he realizes that the girl is going to drown. However, he is resigned to that he can see the future, but not change it, so he says nothing, later on giving another of his bromides when asked how he is doing, exhibiting a false smile despite his sadness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While thinking through the potential bromides, the phrase "gay as cheese" popped in my head. One Google search later, and I found Joan Aiken's "[As Gay As Cheese](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?78453)", which shows up in *[Alfred Hitchcock's Witch's Brew](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?360604)*, another hardback anthology we had in the house, with [this review](http://thesecondpass.com/?p=7856) satisfying me that it's the right one.

> Joan Aiken’s “As Gay As Cheese” concerns a Cornish barber named Mr. Pol who has the uncanny ability to foretell a person’s death merely by running his hands through their hair. He rents the room above his rickety shop to a surly artist who panders to the tourist trade with seascape watercolors. Mr. Pol is an untroubled, fatalistic soul, the very embodiment of equanimity, accepting his strange gift as just one of those things. He whistles cheerfully and speaks in homely cliches as he cuts hair, sweeps floors, and putters around the shop: “I’m as bright as a pearl this morning,” he’ll say, or, “I’m as gay as cheese today.”
>
> One morning a young couple, summer visitors, comes into the shop. Brian is an emotionally abusive bastard who strides in demanding a shave while ordering Mr. Pol to give Fanny a haircut (“You look like a Scotch terrier,” he says to her); Fanny is a scared and gentle fawn of a woman. Throughout, Brian is very anxious to take a certain cliff walk to Pengelly. In fact, he seems extremely focused on this.
>
> As Mr. Pol cuts Fanny’s hair, he feels a shudder run through him like an electric shock. With horror, he sees her floating in the water, bits of seaweed wreathing her face, her thin arm floating out into the water. “Death by drowning,” he foretells. “And so soon.”
>
> The story ends with the surly artist running downstairs too late to sell a painting to Brian and Fanny. He notices Mr. Pol’s pallid face as the barber stares after the departing couple. “What’s the matter?” he asks. “Nothing,” Mr. Pol says. “I’m as gay as cheese.”

Comment: Precisely how gay *is* cheese?